# Asp.net/JQuery: Set session after successful login

Tags: c#, jquery, .net

I am working on a login page that utilizes JQuery to authenticate against a SQL database. I am using ASP.NET WebMethod to validate the user and returning 1 or 0, with 1 being successful and 0 being a failure. If successful, I want to create a session and setting a key, but I am getting an Object Null Exception Error ( I marked the line below).

The login page is pretty straight forward. It takes in a user name/pin and calls ValidateUser when a button is pressed.

I tried googling around and found some examples and tried to copy them, but I still get the same answer.

```
 [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public int ValidateUser(string user_id, string pin_nbr)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[conName].ConnectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("ValidateUser", con);

        try
        {
            da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.VarChar,100).Value = user_id;
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@PinNbr", SqlDbType.VarChar,100).Value = pin_nbr;

            da.Fill(dt);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteToLog(errorMessage.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            da.Dispose();
        }
        if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            Session["UserID"] = user_id;  //<-- OBJECT NULL EXECPTION HERE
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding EnableSession = true to your WebMethod attribute.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
```

This should resolve the problem.